# Send .apk from android code Intent Error

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I want to send .apk file. but i am not able to send it via bluetooth or wifi-direct or any other way.

i have tried everything. i can easily send through e-mail but that too not via Intents but through Mail API.

please find below my Code.

```
public void sendIntent(int x) throws Exception{
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, appnametosend);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getApplicationPath(x));
        sendIntent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");


        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

Below is my logCat:

```
09-01 02:08:33.090: W/Bundle(17609): Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1171)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4454)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:7016)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1414)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at com.example.mysiminfo.MainActivity.sendIntent(MainActivity.java:137)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at com.example.mysiminfo.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:59)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1276)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3067)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3963)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-01 02:08:33.110: W/Bundle(17609):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Help.

Comment: What do you mean "send an APK"?  Send an APK to what?

Comment: i want to send a .apk file from my device to another device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `setType()` takes a MIME type. A path is not a MIME type.

Second, you would need to [use `EXTRA_STREAM` to send a binary attachment](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content).

Third, I would not assume that other apps are necessarily capable of reading the APK from `getApplicationPath(x)`.

Comment: what should i set here in setType() to be a MIME type. Can i write setType("**/**")  ?

Comment: @Anchit: The MIME type is `"application/vnd.android.package-archive"`, as you already have. Do not call `setType()` twice.

Comment: @Anchit: IThe `EXTRA_STREAM` value needs to be a `Uri`.

Comment: Thanks, its working absolutely the way i want it too. Just last query, at present when sending file, it is sending file name as the complete path. is there any way to rename the file that to be sent.

Comment: @Anchit: Not that I am aware of, sorry.