# packing my app and share to other + android

Tags: android, bluetooth, sharing

I'm creating an application for Android and I need a button to send my application to another phone.

I tried to put an apk and send to other but I can't do it.
I'm using this code :

```
Intent sharei=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packa.ge/raw/hafez.apk"));
sharei.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharei, "share"));
```

but it isn't working.

---

I saw a Persian app do this: in a context menu one of the items was :"Send via Bluetooth"  and when I touched this, it sent the apk file to the other phone.

I packed My app and put it to Raw folder to send, but this is not work correctly for 2nd or 3rd phone.

> he said: "i create a application for android i need put button to send my application to other phone", i think he is talking about sending the same application he is running....
>   Andrea Bellitto

Yes. I need to send my running application.

Comment: @GabeSechan It could be done but it really is a bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552517/812598 . However, I'm with you, email is the best way to do that.

Comment: thanks for sharing link :stackoverflow.com/a/18552517/812598  -  but this can't help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the code for changing base.apk to special file name ...

```
 try {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            File srcFile = new File(ai.publicSourceDir);
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "hamed-heydari_Com" + ".apk");
            Tools.copy(srcFile, outputFile);

            Intent share = new Intent();
            share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Tools.getStringByName("installApp") + " " + Tools.getStringByName("app_name"));
            share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share App ..."));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ShareApp", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: What is Tools???

Answer (score 12):

resolved ...

```
try {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    File srcFile = new File(ai.publicSourceDir);
    Intent share = new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(srcFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "PersianCoders"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ShareApp", e.getMessage());
}
```