# How to share my application (the APK file)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-sharing

I want to share my application(APK File) and not a link or text by clicking on button,

this is my share way :

```
Intent shareIntent =new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        Uri uri =Uri.parse("/data/apps/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".apk");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share via"));
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37986490/4665938

Comment: Hello friend
You seem to have experience in Android programming, I have a problem and I want you to solve this problem. I have already posted my problem in stackoverflow but I can not find the right solution. Can you help me?