# How can i share Apk files with share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, share

How to share Apk files directly from your android application when users click on the share button and all sharing sites will be open &share Apk files ??

Comment: The answer was existed here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984988/how-to-send-apk-using-share-intent-programatically-in-android
&& here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816382/packing-my-app-and-share-to-other-android

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationInfo api = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
String apkPath = api.sourceDir;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
```