# how to send .apk file from sdcard via email itent in android?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

i want to send .apk file from sdcard via email intent but not getting attachment.

see below codei try this code but not working for me..

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "email id" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Test Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "go on read the emails");
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            "sPhotoUri=" + Uri.parse("file:/" + "/sdcard/obb/rr.apk"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse("file:/" + "/sdcard/obb/rr.apk"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

This code says could not attachment and not getting mail.

Comment: Try [this1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552517/1289716)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the type of your attachment as below:

```
         emailIntent.setType("application/zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for help i got the mail using this one.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email id"}); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From My App new 1"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/rr.apk"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hard coded `/sdcard/` there is no guarantee that the SD card will have that path

Instead change

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/" + "/sdcard/obb/rr.apk"));
```

to

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + "obb" + File.separatorChar + "rr.apk"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
```

Also change

```
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

to

```
emailIntent.setType("application/zip");
```